# How do I avoid `obj.save()` not to update `updated_at` field?

Tags: python, django

The title alone seems to be vague. Here is the detail.

I have the following Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # deleted for brevity
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    count_visits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)  # counts visit time of posts
```

and added the following code in `blogs.html`:

```
{% if post.created_at == post.updated_at %} 
    Posted {{ post.created_at|naturaltime }} 
{% else %} 
    Updated {{ post.updated_at|naturaltime }} 
{% endif %}
```

then I made a simple `if statement` in `DetailView` to keep track of number of visitors of a certain post:

```
def post_detail(request, title_slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=title_slug)
    session_key = f'key_{title_slug}'

    if not request.session.get(session_key, False):
        obj.count_visits += 1
        obj.save()
        request.session[session_key] = True

    return render(request, 'blogApp/detail.html', {'post': obj})
```

Here is the problem, When I create a post, in list view it shows `Posted now`.

[image]

but as I click the post to view its detail. It shows `Updated now`

[image]

and I think I know what is the problem, when I go to detail view. it creates a `session_key`, increments `obj.count_visits += 1` and save the object `obj.save()`.

When `obj.save()` is called it updates the database including `updated_at` field and that is why I get `Updated now`.

How do I solve this? I want to increment number of `count_views` field, but when object is saved it shouldn't change `updated_at` field.

I hope you help me. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the update directly on the database, bypassing the Django layer:

```
from django.db.models import F

if not request.session.get(session_key, False):
    type(obj).objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(
        count_visits=F('count_visits') + 1
)
```

This will result in the following DB query:

```
UPDATE "<db_table>" SET "count_visits" = ("<db_table>"."count_visits" + 1) \
    WHERE "<db_table>"."id" = <obj.id>
```

The `F`-object is used to resolve references to existing database objects, in this case, we're getting the current value of field `count_visits`. The important property of this is that it can generate expression from the operation and operands (objects) by implementing e.g. `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__`, `__div__` and other dunder methods (actually implemented by its superclass `Combinable`).

---

Another approach would be to take an additional keyword argument to `save` that indicates whether the `updated_at` field should be updated as well. To implement this, at first we need to drop the `auto_now` argument from the field instantiation as well:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):    
    ...
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, set_updated_at=True, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is not None:
            if set_updated_at:
                self.updated_at = timezone.now()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you only need to pass the argument when calling `save` e.g. in this case, it should be `False`:

```
if not request.session.get(session_key, False):
    obj.count_visits += 1
    obj.save(set_updated_at=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. One more tweak to add `request.session[session_key] = True` at the end of the code

Comment: and kindly provide a bit detail about `F`

Comment: So, F() only updated `count_visits` field and didn't effect other fields of the model. right?

Comment: @BasirPayenda `F()` itself doesn't update anything, it's just a class that allows you to fetch values in-place in the database query. `update()` is doing the update and when you call `update()` on a queryset, it will just update the columns you tell it to update.

Comment: Thank You @dirkgroten, this is by far a clear explanation i get